# WCF service hosted on Azure IaaS VM, throwing error

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

We have hosted a simple WCF application on Azure IaaS VM and try to consume it in WinForms application on several clients.

While consuming it on WinForms client application, is it throwing below error

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: 'There was no endpoint
>   listening at
>   http://myazurevm.cloudapp.azure.com/HelloService/ServiceWebHost.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details.'
>
> **Inner Exception**: WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   (404) Not Found.

Also the WSDl document is visible (via Azure DNS) and service URL is working fine. The same is working fine at our dev or local environments.

Comment: yes port 80 is open on azure NSG

Comment: Do you test on your VM? `localhost` could provides service correctly?

Comment: yes , service on localhost is working as expected

Comment: Do you use Windows or Linux VM? Do you open port 80 on VM firewall? This is a classic VM or ARM mode VM?

Comment: this is ARM mode VM, eralier i have opened the port via azure portal , now opened port 80 on VM firewall as well , getting same error

Comment: this is Windows server 2016 datacenter

Comment: For a test, could you try `http://<VM public IP>/HelloService/ServiceWebHost.svc` does it work? Give me the result `netstat -ant|findstr 80`

Comment: can i access this service with windows forms application , i am able to access with web application

Comment: Comments are the wrong place for a discussion. @SourabhGunjawate - please edit your question to include the details that you've been including in comments, and delete all the comments (it's becoming onerous to read through).